# Javascript .blur function and IE6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

I'm working on an existing custom control for an existing website that has to run successfully in IE6 and I need to extend the control to hide part of it once it has lost the focus. Everything is currently working if you click off the control onto just the web page, but it is not hiding if I select another control of the same type. This is the javascript I have currently, the section that isn't working is the .blur(function()):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
                    $('" + checkListDivId + @"').hide();
                    $(document).click(function(e) {
                        if (($('" + checkListDivId + @"').is(':visible'))) {
                            $('" + checkListDivId + @"').hide();
                        }
                    });

                    $('" + checkListDivId + @"').click(function(e) {
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    });

                    $('" + checkListDivId + @"').blur(function() {
                        if (($('" + checkListDivId + @"').is(':visible'))) {
                           $('" + checkListDivId + @"').hide()
                        }
                    });

                    $('" + textBoxDivId + @"').click(function() {
                        if (!($('" + checkListDivId + @"').is(':visible'))) {
                            $('" + checkListDivId + @"').show();
                        }
                        else {
                            $('" + checkListDivId + @"').hide();
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
```

Comment: Have you considered trying raw JavaScript for the blur function?  The latest versions of jQuery most likely aren't giving IE6 the least bit of consideration. You might have better luck with the raw JavaScript. If not, perhaps look at older jQuery code or older jQuery examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$('" + checkListDivId + @"').bind('focusout', function(){
    if (($('" + checkListDivId + @"').is(':visible'))) {
        $('" + checkListDivId + @"').hide()
    }
});
```

Comment: This mostly worked thanks, i was using the wrong part of the control for the .bind but once I changed that it was successful thanks.